# move box from right to top when screen shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have two blocks of text I want to display on the screen. When the screen is wide, I want to display them like this:

```
+---------+  +---------+
| Block B |  | Block A |
+---------+  +---------+
```

When the screen is narrow, I want to display them like this:

```
+---------+
| Block A |
+---------+

+---------+
| Block B |
+---------+
```

Note that it is the block on the right that moves to the top when the screen shrinks.

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

I came up with this:

```css
.frame {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}

#boxA {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 150px;
}

#boxB {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #boxA {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
  }
  #boxB {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="boxA">
    Some text<br/> Other text<br/> More text
  </div>

  <div id="boxB">
    Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Every good boy does fine. A fool and his money are soon parted. Many visitors enter my jail. Some use no pass. Cry havoc, and let loose the
    dogs of war.
  </div>
</div>
```

Which almost works, except because I use the `float: right`, if the text on the left is long enough, it wraps underneath the text on the right, which we don't want. We want two distinct columns.

I tried putting `height: 100%` on `#boxA` but that didn't work.

Note that the width of block A is variable depending on the data, and I want block B to fill the remaining space.

Comment: flexbox + order property : this is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use flexbox:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block a">Block A</div>
  <div class="block b">Block B</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.block.a {
  order: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .block.a {
    order: 0;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1qskxn9y

> Note that the width of block A is variable depending on the data, and I want block B to fill the remaining space.

To satisfy this condition when the viewport is greater than `500px` you can modify the above example with these changes:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    // remove this: align-items: flex-start;
}
// add this:
.block.b {
    flex: 1;
}
```

When less than `500px` each block will fill the viewport width.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1qskxn9y/1/

Comment: Ahhhh. I was unfamiliar with the "order" parameter. Yes, that solves a lot. Thanks.

Comment: A very useful tool for everything related to flex-box can be found here: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 0):

Can also be achieved by using floats:

HTML:

```
<div class="block">Block</div>
<div class="block">Block B</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 54px;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .block {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2nkxvfy8/

Comment: I tried something like this but I couldn't get it to work when the widths of the two boxes were not fixed. I want "block B" to take as much space as necessary to not wrap, and "block A" to take the remaining space. Whatever the available space is.

Comment: This can be done with a little bit more complex markup (wrapping each of the 2 divs) and playing with `display: inline`, but I think using flex will probably be easier and has a wide enough browser support nowadays.